# iOS App Store Promo Code says "Must be redeemed using a Mac"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have a new app ready in the App Store with status:

"Pending Developer Release"

I created 5 App Promo Codes, so I can get people to test/review it before release. When I try to redeem a code on an iPhone I get an error:

"This code must be redeemed using a Mac.
On your Mac, go to App Store > Account > Redeem Gift Card"

but this is an iOS game, nothing to do with Mac. Out of interest, I tried doing as it says and redeem on Mac and then I get error:

"This code must be redeemed on an iOS device" (!)

Has anyone else seen this error? Any idea how to get Promo Codes working?

Comment: You can't redeem promo codes if the app isn't released. You can use TestFlight to make the app available for testing before it is released.

Comment: Surely the whole point of APP promo codes is to give out to reviewers before release? It’s a free app.

Comment: Users can't redeem a code for an app that hasn't been released.  What you need to do is set a release date in the future and then release the app; It won't be available generally until that date but promo codes can be redeemed

Comment: Hmm. Well it has been approved and I selected manually release and so it status is now Pending Developer Release which I would have thought is the same as setting a future release date with regards to Promo codes,

Comment: No, it is pending developer release.  You need to actually select a date and release it

Comment: It does let me create promo codes and the error I get does not say they are invalid so you are saying these are App Store bugs and really it should not allow promo codes to be created using manual releases.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it shouldn't allow the promo codes to be created, but certainly this is an issue that [has a long history](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/22455)

Comment: OK, interesting. I will look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Apple not allowing for the first release but you can achieve it by this hack

1. Release the app in your region only, for me I have selected India only (Revert back once you done #3)
2. Now, you can try same to Redeem Code, it will work
3. Once you done with the Redeem, you can remove your region/country(Deselect all) until you complete review of your app.

Enjoy